# Detox mocking using file extension e2e.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, detox

I'm using Detox as an end to end testing framework for a react native application. I'd like to mock the results of API requests in order to reduce flakiness and time for testing.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md), I should be able to have Metro overwrite a module using the file extension e2e.js.

I'm unable to get this working and I'm not entirely sure why. Most documentation and existing questions relate to using react-native-repackager, but as of RN 0.55.0, this is no longer needed.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated!

EDIT:

`RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js react-native start` works fine

`RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js xcodebuild -project <other params>` as the detox build script and `detox test -c ios.sim.release` does not work

Comment: Could you share your CLI configuration file? I can't make this work.

Comment: `rn-cli.config.js`



`module.exports = {
  getSourceExts: () =>
    process.env.RN_SRC_EXT ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',') : [],
};`
@milo

Comment: Could you also share your Api.e2e.js to see how you handle the api call ?

Comment: Api.e2e.js just exported the same functions as Api.js, except they would just return promises that resolved to our mocked output. We no longer use this, and I would probably suggest using something like nock to get a more realistic mocking of the api calls

Comment: I have this issue in react-native 0.61.5!! any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Detox for a while since it was previously too flaky. Maybe post a separate question with more specifics :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rm -rf ios/build`

Had to clear my previous build cache and files, then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

for me, there was a mismatch between `binaryPath` and actual binary path.